# Couchbase operator issue

Tags: couchbase

Couchbase operator (enterprise 1.2) helm chart having an issue

With new couchbase cluster following issue is happening always

couchbase-operator     couchbase-operator-0.1.2        1.2

```
time="2019-06-25T04:22:14Z" level=error msg="failed to reconcile: unable to get buckets from cluster: [Client error `unmarshal json response`: json: cannot unmarsh
al number 897.8978978978979 into Go struct field BucketBasicStats.diskFetches of type int], [Client error `unmarshal json response`: json: cannot unmarshal number
897.8978978978979 into Go struct field BucketBasicStats.diskFetches of type int], [Client error `unmarshal json response`: json: cannot unmarshal number 897.897897
8978979 into Go struct field BucketBasicStats.diskFetches of type int]" cluster-name=couchbase-cluster-couchbase-cluster module=cluster
time="2019-06-25T04:22:22Z" level=error msg="failed to reconcile: unable to get buckets from cluster: [Client error `unmarshal json response`: json: cannot unmarsh
al number 575.7622377622378 into Go struct field BucketBasicStats.diskFetches of type int], [Client error `unmarshal json response`: json: cannot unmarshal number
575.7622377622378 into Go struct field BucketBasicStats.diskFetches of type int], [Client error `unmarshal json response`: json: cannot unmarshal number 575.762237
7622378 into Go struct field BucketBasicStats.diskFetches of type int]" cluster-name=couchbase-cluster-couchbase-cluster module=cluster
```

Answer (score 3):

Update: This is now fixed [as of release 1.2.1](https://docs.couchbase.com/operator/1.2/release-notes.html)

Oh that's a good one!  Yes it appears *diskFetches* is actually a rate per second and not an integer counter as assumed by the client code.

<s>Nothing we can do at the moment, but I have flagged as a critical fix and will be in 1.2.1 shortly.</s>  For your information, the operator ensures the cluster is correctly sized, balanced and healthy before doing any bucket manipulations (where it fails), so your data is safe.

What I can suggest is you set *spec.disableBucketManagement* to true in your cluster definition and create buckets either with the UI or a client SDK, this will avoid the condition completely until we can get a hot-fix out.